# Need to find max value with text & number combination

Tags: excel, vba, text, numbers

I have some data in a column of excel sheet. (Text-Number combination) Like:

```
AAA-32 
BBB-54
AAA-221
CCC-05
DDD-212
```

*Text would be always 3 characters long & is always followed by a " - "* then a number.

I need to find max value for AAA, BBB, CCC ..& other texts that has largest number.

Max value for AAA is "AAA-221", similarly want for other characters (BBB,CCC..)

How can achieve it using VBA ?

```
`Data is present in column A
'lRow = Last Row
`tchar contains no. of unique characters, here 4 (AAA,BBB,CCC,DDD)

Dim i as Integer, tchar as Integer, tArray() as String, rng as Range

'Copying unique characters from col A into col Z. (Ignore Cell A1, Z1)
Range("A2:A" & lRow).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Range("Z2"), Unique:=True

'To get tchar
Range("Z2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
tchar = Selection.Rows.Count

'Range with unique characters
Set rng = Range("Z2", "Z" & lRow)

'Re-Define array
ReDim tArray(tchar)

'Getting unique characters into array
For i = 1 To tchar
tArray(i) = rng.Item(i).Value
Next i

'Separated Text & Numbers  into col B & C
'Col B has text (AAA,BBB...)
'Col C has numbers (32, 54, 221 ..)

'Now to use tArray() to traverse in col B & get max value from col C

'**I am stuck here**
```

Comment: Why do you need VBA at all? Just use the text-to-column tool in Excel (delimit by dash), then use a MAXIF formula.

Comment: To implement logic in a macro

Comment: Let me rephrase my question then: Why do you need a macro at all?

Comment: Data is huge & this is a repetitive task. Hence Macro

Comment: Stack overflow is not a code for me or give me the steps or teach me to code site.  If you have existing code that does not work, please [edit] the post to include it along with a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The task looks like a classic case for using a Dictionary object

```
Option Explicit

Sub SelectMax()
    Dim Key As String, Value As Long, x As Variant, a As Variant, cnt As Long
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        For Each x In Intersect(.Columns("A"), .UsedRange)
            a = Split(x, "-")
            
            Key = a(0): Value = Val(a(1))
            
            If dict.exists(Key) Then
                If Value > dict(Key) Then dict(Key) = Value
            Else
                dict.Add Key, Value
            End If
        Next
        
        ' output the result
        Range("B1") = "Max" 'header
        cnt = 1
        For Each x In dict.Keys
            Range("B1").Offset(cnt) = x & "-" & dict(x)
            cnt = cnt + 1
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: oooh this worked.. For me this is a big jump from array or max.

Answer (score 0):

Without VBA you could use the **array formula**:

```
=MAX(IF(LEFT(A1:A5,3)="AAA",--MID(A1:A5,5,99),""))
```

[image]

so with VBA:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim v As Variant
    v = Evaluate("MAX(IF(LEFT(A1:A5,3)=""AAA"",--MID(A1:A5,5,99),""""))")
    MsgBox v
End Sub
```

Repeat or loop for each prefix.